# Why does this blocking socket read return zero and no error?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, io

This code running on Linux:

```
int r, c;
...
assert(0 == (O_NONBLOCK & fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0)));
errno = 0;
r = read(sockfd, &c, 1);
if (r == 0 && errno == 0) { 
    printf("What gives?\n");
}
...
```

which is performing a read from a socket, will occasionally return zero (in `r`) and leave `errno` set to zero (0) as well. ***What situation am I encountering?*** I'd really like to have the read block unless there is an error.

Comment: I believe this happens when the client closes their end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This means that the client finished sending data (eg: did a `shutdown` for writing), and you already read all available data.

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On  success,  the  number of bytes read is returned
>      (zero indicates end of file),
>      and the file position is advanced by this number.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the `read` man page says:

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end
>   of file)

so `0` means that your socket is closed.

Comment: it's not necessarily fully closed, you can half-close a socket